# Is there a way to skip the end credits in DMC?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

Is there a .bik file I can delete or something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can delete the end credits video. You can definitely delete the intro videos though.

1. Navigate to \DevilGame\Movies\
2. Rename or delete the files:

   > Capcom.bik
   >   UE3_logo.bik
   >   AMDlogo.bik

Maybe see what's located in that folder for the end game credits